# How can I "undelete" files on my 1.5 tb external drive?

Tags: data-recovery

I accidentally erased my 1.5 tb external hd and need to recover/restore or undo this mistake to save 1.3 tb worth of music mp3's, mp4's, pictures, and programs etc. I am getting a message saying that the disc needs to be formated! What should I do?

Comment: What is the filesystem of the disk? (And the operating system of your computer?). ext*/Linux or NTFS/Windows...

Comment: Without knowing your operating system and file system, and how you erased your HDD, your question would be closed, as we don't know what you're asking for. There are hudrends for recovery software, just Google it or check related questions.

Comment: See e.g. [How to recover data in formatted hard disk and already installed a new OS](http://superuser.com/questions/790527/how-to-recover-data-in-formatted-hard-disk-and-already-installed-a-new-os), [How to recover data from old drives of different types?](http://superuser.com/questions/181576/how-to-recover-data-from-old-drives-of-different-types), [etc.](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery)

Answer (score 0):

There is no undelete, but you can use a data recovery software to search the hard disk for deleted files and try to recover them.
There are a lot of applications can do this like: Kernel for Windows Data Recovery, Wondershare Data Recovery, and many others.
Check this article that i have wrote for more info about the applications and unique features for each one, so you can decide.
http://www.itprostuff.com/articles/recover-deleted-lost-files.html